# Unable to intercept and mock SQL endpoint with adviceWith in Camel

Tags: java, apache-camel

I'm trying to unit test a route with a SQL endpoint but fail due to lack of configured Datasource.

This is my code:

```
public class TestSqlRouteTest extends CamelTestSupport {
    @Override
    public boolean isUseAdviceWith() {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    @Before
    public void setUp() throws Exception {
        super.setUp();

        context.addRoutes(new RouteBuilder() {
            @Override
            public void configure() {
                from("direct:sql").routeId("directsql").to("sql://select 1 from DUAL").end();
            }
        });

        context.getRouteDefinition("directsql")
                .adviceWith(context, new AdviceWithRouteBuilder() {
                    @Override
                    public void configure() {
                        interceptSendToEndpoint("sql:*").to("mock:sql").skipSendToOriginalEndpoint();
                    }
                });
    }

    /**
     * Test sql.
     *
     * @throws Exception the exception
     */
    @Test
    public void testSQL() throws Exception {
        context.start();
        template.sendBody("mock:sql", "body");

        final MockEndpoint mockSQL = getMockEndpoint("mock:sql");
        mockSQL.expectedMessageCount(1);
        mockSQL.assertIsSatisfied();

        assertMockEndpointsSatisfied();
        context.stop();
    }

}
```

The error I get is

```
org.apache.camel.FailedToCreateRouteException: Failed to create route directsql at: >>> To[sql://select 1 from DUAL] <<< in route: Route(directsql)[[From[direct:sql]] -> [To[sql://select 1 fr... because of Failed to resolve endpoint: sql://select%201%20from%20DUAL due to: DataSource must be configured
```

I'm using Camel 2.22.0 and Java 8.

Please advice (pardon the pun)

M

**EDIT**: Added this change with the same result: SQL component gets started and expecting Datasource.

Added some more components, jms, http and they are mocked perfectly…

```
@Override
    @Before
    public void setUp() throws Exception {
        super.setUp();

        context.addRoutes(new RouteBuilder() {
            @Override
            public void configure() {
                from("direct:sql")
                        .routeId("directsql")
                        .to("jms:queue:whatever")
                        .to("http://www.whatever.com")
                        .to("sql://select 1 from DUAL")
                        .end();
            }
        });

        context.getRouteDefinition("directsql")
                .adviceWith(context, new AdviceWithRouteBuilder() {
                    @Override
                    public void configure() throws Exception {
                        mockEndpoints();
                    }
                });
    }
```

This is from the log:

```
2018-07-19 14:21:03.465  INFO   --- [           main] org.apache.camel.model.RouteDefinition   : Adviced route before/after as XML:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<route xmlns="http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring" customId="true" id="directsql">
    <from uri="direct:sql"/>
    <to uri="jms:queue:whatever"/>
    <to uri="http://www.whatever.com"/>
    <to uri="sql://select 1 from DUAL"/>
</route>

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<route xmlns="http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring" customId="true" id="directsql">
    <from uri="direct:sql"/>
    <to uri="jms:queue:whatever"/>
    <to uri="http://www.whatever.com"/>
    <to uri="sql://select 1 from DUAL"/>
</route>
```

As far as I can see the SQL component is never adviced:

```
2018-07-19 14:21:03.488  INFO   --- [           main] .c.i.InterceptSendToMockEndpointStrategy : Adviced endpoint [direct://sql] with mock endpoint [mock:direct:sql]
```

…

```
2018-07-19 14:21:03.541  INFO   --- [           main] .c.i.InterceptSendToMockEndpointStrategy : Adviced endpoint [jms://queue:whatever] with mock endpoint [mock:jms:queue:whatever]
```

…

```
2018-07-19 14:21:03.634  INFO   --- [           main] .c.i.InterceptSendToMockEndpointStrategy : Adviced endpoint [http://www.whatever.com] with mock endpoint [mock:http:www.whatever.com]
```

**EDIT 2:**
Added this to the class and now I can mock SQL component…

This datasource is never used, only for requirements…

```
@Override
    protected JndiRegistry createRegistry() throws Exception {
        final JndiRegistry jndi = super.createRegistry();
        final BasicDataSource ds = new BasicDataSource();
        ds.setDriverClassName("org.h2.Driver");
        ds.setUrl("jdbc:h2:mem:default");
        jndi.bind("dataSource", ds);

        return jndi;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

When you use interceptors like in your unit test, then the component/endpoint must be valid to be able to startup. You would also need the component on the classpath etc.

Instead of using interceptors you can use advice with, to remove / replace parts of the route. So what you can do is to replace the sql endpoint with a mock endpoint. See more details about adviceWith in the documentation for how to do that: http://camel.apache.org/advicewith.html

Comment: OK thanks, but I thought I was doing that in my code. What is wrong, then?

Comment: I changed the code but afaik the sql is never adviced and mocked

Answer (score 0):

Add this method to fulfill the requirements:

```
@Override
    protected JndiRegistry createRegistry() throws Exception {
        final JndiRegistry jndi = super.createRegistry();
        final BasicDataSource ds = new BasicDataSource();
        ds.setDriverClassName("org.h2.Driver");
        ds.setUrl("jdbc:h2:mem:default");
        jndi.bind("dataSource", ds);

        return jndi;
    }
```

The datasource can be anything valid in pom, I chose h2 since it's simple… The datasource is never used in my example.